# parent url of an opensocial container

Tags: javascript, opensocial

Is there a way to get the "parent url" of an Opensocial container?

Google Sites embeds gadgets through an Opensocial container and I'd like to grab the parent's URL to generate a message.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is.

`gadgets.util.getUrlParameters()["parent"]` or 
`gadgets.util.getUrlParameters().parent`

shoud give you the parent url.